# How to read a plist data and get int from it?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Currently using cocos2d. I have a plist data name myplist.plist. Inside the plist are all integers.. How do i read the data and the int in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *dictionaryPath = [path stringbyAppendingPathComponent:@"myplist.plist"];

NSDictionary *integerDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:dictionaryPath];

int myInteger1 = [[integerDictionary objectForKey:@"integer1"] intValue];
int myInteger2 = [[integerDictionary objectForKey:@"integer2"] intValue];
// etc etc
```

Comment: The correct capitalization is "stringByAppendingPathComponent"